# Reading information from a website c#

Tags: c#, java, web

In the project I have in mind I want to be able to look at a website, retrieve text from that website, and do something with that information later.

My question is what is the best way to retrieve the data(text) from the website. I am unsure about how to do this when dealing with a static page vs dealing with a dynamic page.

From some searching I found this:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("anysite.com");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            // Read the content. 
            string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            reader.Close();
        }

        response.Close();
```

So from running this on my own I can see it returns the html code from a website, not exactly what I'm looking for. I eventually want to be able to type in a site (such as a news article), and return the contents of the article. Is this possible in c# or Java?

Thanks

Comment: I fail to see what you're missing.  You can turn this whole thing into a method that returnst he resulting string instead of printing it to the console, and that accepts a URL as a string to allow you to pass in any (possibly dynamically generated) string you want.

Comment: Ah, screen scraping. Think of yourself as a sculptor who merely needs to remove everything that isn't the article in order to (mis)appropriate someone else's content.

Comment: try http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Answer (score 1):

I hate to brake this to you but that's how webpages looks, it's a long stream of html markup/content. This gets rendered by the browser as what you see on your screen. The only way I can think of is to parse to html by yourself.

After a quick search on google I found this stack overflow article.
[What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

but I'm betting you figured this would be a bit easier than you expected, but that's the fun in programming always challenging problems

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a WebClient:

```
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
   string htmlFromPage = webClient.DownloadString("http://myurl.com");
}
```

In the above example `htmlFromPage` will contain the HTML which you can then parse to find the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called *web scraping*, and there are plenty of libraries that do just that for both Java and C#. It doesn't really matter if the target site is static or dynamic since both output HTML in the end. JavaScript or Flash heavy sites on the other hand tend to be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
```

`string webData = wc.DownloadString("anysite.com");`